# The ApacheDS LDAP cann't startup on Centos7

Tags: ldap, centos7, apacheds

My APACHEDS LDAP can't startup today. It works very fine for long time.
I checked the log, but seems like no similar answers for me.

Would you please help me

[17:08:44] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:08:44] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:08:44] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:08:44] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:08:44] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:08:44] ERROR [org.apache.directory.server.wrapper.ApacheDsTanukiWrapper] - Failed to start the service.
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapOtherException: maximum size must not be negative
at org.apache.directory.server.core.api.partition.AbstractPartition.initialize(AbstractPartition.java:91)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService.initialize(DefaultDirectoryService.java:1986)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService.startup(DefaultDirectoryService.java:1244)
at org.apache.directory.server.ApacheDsService.initDirectoryService(ApacheDsService.java:390)
at org.apache.directory.server.ApacheDsService.start(ApacheDsService.java:205)
at org.apache.directory.server.ApacheDsService.start(ApacheDsService.java:152)
at org.apache.directory.server.wrapper.ApacheDsTanukiWrapper.start(ApacheDsTanukiWrapper.java:175)
at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)
Caused by: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapOtherException: maximum size must not be negative
at org.apache.directory.server.core.api.partition.AbstractPartition.initialize(AbstractPartition.java:91)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.shared.partition.DefaultPartitionNexus.addContextPartition(DefaultPartitionNexus.java:834)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.shared.partition.DefaultPartitionNexus.doInit(DefaultPartitionNexus.java:242)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.api.partition.AbstractPartition.initialize(AbstractPartition.java:86)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maximum size must not be negative
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.requireArgument(Caffeine.java:173)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.maximumSize(Caffeine.java:316)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.AbstractBTreePartition.doInit(AbstractBTreePartition.java:632)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmPartition.doInit(JdbmPartition.java:511)
at org.apache.directory.server.core.api.partition.AbstractPartition.initialize(AbstractPartition.java:86)

Answer (score 0):

At last I did not resolve this issue, but it should related to

> .LdapOtherException: maximum size must not be negative at

I did not change any size value at all, so I imaged the file is not well recognized by system somehow. The default value can be found in conf folder.

Anyway, I reinstalled all.